# Compare attribute values using Xpath

Tags: xpath

Given the following document structure, how could i check if two attribute values match using Xpath?

```
<document lang="en">
<element lang="en"></element>
<element lang="sv"></element>
<element lang="fr"></element>
</document>
```

What i am looking for is something like:

```
//document[@lang="[//element[@lang]"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will return all `<document>` nodes having `lang` attribute value match any child node `<element>`'s `lang` attribute :

```
//document[@lang = element/@lang]
```

Answer (score 3):

Specifically to your example, you can use:

```
//document[@lang=child::element/@lang]
```

If you are just checking whether a match exists, you can wrap it in a `boolean`:

```
boolean(//document[@lang=child::element/@lang])
```

If you want to select the matched element, you can check by `ancestor`:

```
//element[@lang=ancestor::document[1]/@lang]
```

If you want to match any nodes that have matching attributes elsewhere, you can do something like this:

```
//node()[@lang=following::node()/@lang]
```

That should match the first node that has a match elsewhere in the document.

Answer (score 0):

This example should work:

```
//document/@lang[. = //element/@lang]
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath is a *query language*. Its primary use is to *find* XML nodes, not "checking" if such and such a condition is true or not.

A task like this is better suited for the host language XPath is embedded into, for example XSLT. In XSLT, there is an `xsl:if` element for this.

For example, write a template like

```
<xsl:template match="/document">
  <xsl:if test="@lang = element/@lang">
    <true/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The template above matches `document` and returns a `<true/>` element, if the attribute value of an `element` element is the same as the value of `document/@lang`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately i cant use XSL/XSLT in this situation.